# Obtain child node based on attribute of parent node

Tags: c#, xml, linq, crystal-reports, linq-to-xml

I have a CrystalReport report in XML (sorry for the verboseness, I cut out most sample data)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<FormattedReport xmlns = 'urn:crystal-reports:schemas' xmlns:xsi = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance'>
<FormattedAreaPair Level="0" Type="Report">
<FormattedAreaPair Level="1" Type="Details">
<FormattedArea Type="Details">
<FormattedSections>
<FormattedSection SectionNumber="0">
<FormattedReportObjects>
<FormattedReportObject xsi:type="CTFormattedField" Type="xsd:string" FieldName="{AIRCRAFT.Tail Number}"><ObjectName>Field2</ObjectName>
<FormattedValue>C-FBCS</FormattedValue>
<Value>C-FBCS</Value>
</FormattedReportObject>
<FormattedReportObject xsi:type="CTFormattedField" Type="xsd:string" FieldName="{AIRCRAFT.Type ID}"><ObjectName>Field8</ObjectName>
<FormattedValue>DHC8</FormattedValue>
<Value>DHC8</Value>
</FormattedReportObject>
<FormattedReportObject xsi:type="CTFormattedField" Type="xsd:unsignedLong" FieldName="{TRIP LEGS.Trip Number}"><ObjectName>Field9</ObjectName>
<FormattedValue>68344</FormattedValue>
<Value>68344.00</Value>
</FormattedReportObject>
</FormattedReportObjects>
</FormattedSection>
</FormattedSections>
</FormattedArea>
</FormattedAreaPair>
<FormattedAreaPair Level="1" Type="Details">
<FormattedArea Type="Details">
<FormattedSections>
<FormattedSection SectionNumber="0">
<FormattedReportObjects>
<FormattedReportObject xsi:type="CTFormattedField" Type="xsd:string" FieldName="{AIRCRAFT.Tail Number}"><ObjectName>Field2</ObjectName>
<FormattedValue>C-FBCS</FormattedValue>
<Value>C-FBCS</Value>
</FormattedReportObject>
<FormattedReportObject xsi:type="CTFormattedField" Type="xsd:string" FieldName="{AIRCRAFT.Type ID}"><ObjectName>Field8</ObjectName>
<FormattedValue>DHC8</FormattedValue>
<Value>DHC8</Value>
</FormattedReportObject>
<FormattedReportObject xsi:type="CTFormattedField" Type="xsd:unsignedLong" FieldName="{TRIP LEGS.Trip Number}"><ObjectName>Field9</ObjectName>
<FormattedValue>68344</FormattedValue>
<Value>68344.00</Value>
</FormattedReportObject>
</FormattedReportObjects>
</FormattedSection>
</FormattedSections>
</FormattedArea>
</FormattedAreaPair>
...
</FormattedAreaPair>
</FormattedReport>
```

I am attempting to use a LINQ to XML query to extract the 
*Value* node based on the parent node's *FieldName* attribute and place those into an object. There is no unique attribute for Value or the parents of FormattedReportObject nodes.  So far here is my code to do so

```
from fs in xDoc.Descendants("FormattedSection")
select new FlightSchedule
{
  AircraftType = from fos in fs.Descendants("FormattedReportObjects")
                 from fo in fs.Descendants("FormattedReportObject")
                 where fo.Attribute("FieldName").Value.Equals("{AIRCRAFT.Type ID}")
                 from e in fo.Element("Value")
                 select e.Value),
  ....
};
```

I keep getting errors:

> An expression of type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' is not allowed in a subsequent from clause in a query expression with source type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'. Type inference failed in the call to 'SelectMany')

or if I don't get an error I end up retrieving nothing.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated on improving my query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has several problems. First, the thing the compiler is complaining about is, as @MizardX mentioned, that you are using `fo.Element("Value")` as if it was a sequence. What you probably want is to write `let e = fo.Element("Value")` (or skip this part completely and directly write `select fo.Element("Value").Value`).

Another problem is that your XML is using a namespace, but you aren't. This means that you should create a `XNamespace` object and use it wherever you have element names.

Also, the way your code is written, `AircraftType` is a sequence of strings. I assume this is not what you wanted.

And seeing that you want to do the same thing for different values of `FieldName`, you probably want to make this into a method.

With all the problems mentioned above fixed, the code should look something like this:

```
static readonly XNamespace ns = XNamespace.Get("urn:crystal-reports:schemas");

string GetFieldValue(XElement fs, string fieldName)
{
    return (from fo in fs.Descendants(ns + "FormattedReportObject")
            where fo.Attribute("FieldName").Value == fieldName
            let e = fo.Element(ns + "Value")
            select e.Value).Single();
}
…
var flts = (from fs in xDoc.Descendants(ns + "FormattedSection")
            select new FlightSchedule
            {
                AircraftType = GetFieldValue(fs, "{AIRCRAFT.Type ID}"),
                …
            }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

`fo.Element("Value")` returns an `XElement`-object. What you want is probably `fo.Elements("Value")` (note the plural 's').

The error message was complaining that it didn't know how to iterate over the `XElement` object.

The reason you are not getting any results, is that the XML-file is using namespaces. To find elements outside the default namespace, you need to prefix the namespace before the node name.

I also noticed that you are not using the `fos` variable, so that loop is unnecessary. `fs.Decendants()` is already giving you the correct result.

```
List<FlightSchedule> flts =
    (from fs in xDoc.Descendants("{urn:crystal-reports:schemas}FormattedSection")
     select new FlightSchedule
     {
         AircraftType =
             (from fo in fs.Descendants("{urn:crystal-reports:schemas}FormattedReportObject")
              where fo.Attribute("FieldName").Value == "{AIRCRAFT.Type ID}"
              from e in fo.Elements("{urn:crystal-reports:schemas}Value")
              select e.Value),
                          ....
     }).ToList();
```